# fixed width LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, fixed

I'm trying to get two linear layout side by side and put content inside of it.

I want the two linear layouts to be side by side, but the left one should take about 3/4 of the screen and the right one the rest of it.

This is my code: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1682040

But the two linear layouts always change the width and the height depending on the content.

How can I have two linear layouts side by side with fixed width and height?

A better solution with RelativeLayout is always welcome.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: its good if you can share any image of your output

Comment: Done =) sorry, I forgot

Comment: try this give first Linear layout **`android:layout_weight=".75"`** and give second Linear layout  **`android:layout_weight=".25"`**

Comment: Do u change something in the params of the layouts programmatically ?

Comment: @NileshRathod, it didn't work.

Comment: @Nmna, no, I don't.

Answer (score 4):

Use `layout_weight` property of `LinearLayout` and  `android:weightSum` property for parent layout.

Do Something like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:weightSum="1">
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".75" // For First layout to 3/4
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            //First Layout content Here
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25" // For Second layout to rest of screen
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
               //Second Layout Content Here
           </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that you asked for a solution with the `LinearLayout` but I suggest you to solve this problem with the `ConstraintLayout`. You will get incredible performance improvements without nested view.

In this sample I added a `vertical guideline at 75%` of from the left of the screen. I have only to remove the nested LinearLayouts and add the constraints to your views!

Try it out!

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="628dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/repository_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/repository_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repository_fork_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repository_star_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="628dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_last_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mock Name"
        android:textColor="@color/lightGray" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this give Your first `LinearLayout` **`android:layout_weight=".75"`** so it can take 3/4 space in screen
than assign **`android:layout_weight="0.25"`** to Your second `LinearLayout` so it can take remaining  space

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repository_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AAAAA"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repository_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="AAAAA"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/repository_fork_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="123"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/repository_star_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="123"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_image"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AAAAA"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_last_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mock Name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorRed" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why Down vote...? Please also mention a valid reason so i can improve my answer

Comment: I didn't down vote. I tryied your solution, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the weight sum to 4 in the parent layout and add weight as 3 for  child linear layout so it can take 3/4 space and 1 to child linear layout so that it will take the remaining space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        //Your contents

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        //Your contents

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: On android studio looks good but when I run on emulator it breaks because the “description” field is long

Answer (score 0):

Seems like both of the weights are set to "1". Have you tried ".5"?

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_weight="0.50"
    android:gravity="left|center">
```

Comment: If they both have same weight isn't it supposed to split the space in exactly 2 ? I think won't make any difference if they are both on 0.5

Comment: Yes, having it split like that is exactly in the middle. The desired weight or importance (see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) is up to the desired result.  A more elaborate or flexible layout would be a ContraintLayout, or use a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I would also go for a `RelativeLayout` with 2 childs in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have added weight

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repository_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AAAAA"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repository_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="AAAAA"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/repository_fork_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="123"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/repository_star_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="123"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_image"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AAAAA"
            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_last_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mock Name"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGray" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for 3/4 add .75

Answer (score 0):

First remove weightSum attribute from parent layout.

If you want your first layout to be 3/4 of you should put weight 0.75 and 0.25 (1/4) for the other one like here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="15dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left|center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/repository_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/repository_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repository_fork_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/repository_star_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:gravity="center">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_last_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mock Name"
        android:textColor="@color/lightGray"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_txt"
                    android:gravity="center"
                  />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_txt"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```